# Expo (React-Native) has created a zombie redirect in Firefox. How to remove?

Tags: node.js, firefox, expo

So, I experimented with React-native. I used:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Now that I'm done, I killed expo, I went back to my normal development, a Node.JS server and Angular8 front end. I type:

http://localhost

in Firefox and I get ... the Expo app.

wut?

I killed my node server, still get the exp app. If I check from the command prompt:

```
[C:\]telnet localhost 80
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

Yet if I go to Firefox, and go to Localhost, I get the Expo app.

Interestingly, from Edge I don't.

So, I check extensions and add-ons in Firefox, but don't see anything that would change 'http://localhost'.

Oddly, If I use

http://192.168.1.101

I DO get my actual node.js app once I run it.

So why and how has Expo ganked my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally fixed this.

What happened is that Expo registered a "Service Worker" for localhost, and that seems to take precedance over any ACTUAL web serer running on Localhost.

There's a lot of documentation for Chrome, but not firefox. (Beware any mono-culture!) Here's how you fix it in Firefox:

1. Open a new tab
2. Enter a URL of about:serviceworkers
3. Scroll down until you find "localhost"
4. Click on "Unregister"

Now when you go to http://localhost you will get your actual running process.